# Update Global Variable with Ajax Success Result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, callback, global-variables

I have the below script. When I execute the ajax function, it correctly prints photobombAvatar in the console with an updated value. However, I am having trouble updating photobombAvatar as a global variable.

```
<script>
var photobombAvatar = "<?php echo $this->user_data['avatar']; ?>";

$(function () {

    var uploader = new ss.SimpleUpload({
        button: btn,
        url: '<?php echo $this->form_action; ?>',
        sessionProgressUrl: 'data/js/plugins/thisSCRIPT.php',
        name: 'file',
        debug: true,
        data: {name: 'upload_avatar'},
        responseType: 'json',
        onSubmit: function (filename, ext) {
        // do a bunch of stuff
        },

        onComplete: function(file, json) {
            if (json.success) {
                var pic = new Pic();
                var photobombAvatar = json.success;
                pic.src = json.success;
            }
            console.log(photobombAvatar);  
        }
    });
});


 //another js fxn that uses the updated global photobombAvatar.

</script>
```

I have read a bunch of examples using a callback function but cannot seem to get it to work. Here is one example I tried:

```
 <script>
var photobombAvatar = "<?php echo $this->user_data['avatar']; ?>";

$(function photobomb(callback) {

    var uploader = new ss.SimpleUpload({
        button: btn,
        url: '<?php echo $this->form_action; ?>',
        sessionProgressUrl: 'data/js/plugins/thisSCRIPT.php',
        name: 'file',
        debug: true,
        data: {name: 'upload_avatar'},
        responseType: 'json',
        onSubmit: function (filename, ext) {
        // do a bunch of stuff
        },

        onComplete: function(file, json) {
            if (json.success) {
                var pic = new Pic();
                var photobombAvatar = json.success;
                pic.src = json.success;
                callback(json);
            }
            console.log(photobombAvatar); 
            updatedVAR(photobombAvatar); 
        }
    });
});

photobomb();

function updatedVAR(photobombAvatar) {
    console.log(photobombAvatar);

    // do the rest of the js I need with the updated photobombAvatar value.
}

</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `photobombAvatar` new in the onComplete function. Remove the `var` before photobombAvatar. like:

```
 onComplete: function(file, json) {
            if (json.success) {
                var pic = new Pic();
                var photobombAvatar = json.success;
                pic.src = json.success;
                callback(json);
            }
```

change to:

```
 onComplete: function(file, json) {
            if (json.success) {
                var pic = new Pic();
                photobombAvatar = json.success;
                pic.src = json.success;
                callback(json);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike Aron. That still does not update the global variable for subsequent functions. Any ideas?